# if user toggle a one div then other toggled div should close automatically

Tags: html, vue.js

Here I ave written a vue.js code. Here I have tried to achieve to toggle a div. if i will click a button "deals of the day" then I am toggling a other div. similarly I am doing with all other three divs. And it is working fine but i want to enhance this functionality like if user clicks on one button then div will toggle then similarly if user clicks on other button to toggle a div then previously toggle div should automatically close how to achieve this in vue.js

```
<script>
    new Vue({
 el: '#category_app',
 data () {
   return {
     toggle: false,
     latestClassifieds: false,
     latestcomments: false,
   }
 },
})
</script>
```

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div @click='toggletwo = !toggletwo' class="dealOfDay">Deal of the day</div>
        <div v-show='toggletwo' class="DayListings">Deals of the day Listings</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div @click='latestClassifieds = !latestClassifieds' class="dealOfDay">Advertiser</div>
        <div v-show='latestClassifieds'>Advertise listings</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div @click='latestcomments = !latestcomments' class="dealOfDay">Latest Classifieds</div>
        <div v-show='latestcomments'>Latest classified listings</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution could be:

```js
<script>
new Vue({
 el: '#category_app',
 data () {
   return {
     toggle: 1
   }
 }
})
</script>
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div @click='toggle = 1' class="dealOfDay">Deal of the day</div>
        <div v-show='toggle === 1' class="DayListings">Deals of the day Listings</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div @click='toggle = 2' class="dealOfDay">Advertiser</div>
        <div v-show='toggle === 2'>Advertise listings</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div @click='toggle = 3' class="dealOfDay">Latest Classifieds</div>
        <div v-show='toggle === 3'>Latest classified listings</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can set `toggle` variable to `0` by default if you don't want to have any of them open after page is loaded.

Comment: the code is working fine. but if i want to close the div then how should i do that. because if I am clicking to close the toggle it is closing

Comment: to do that you could simply modify, 
`<div @click='toggleDiv(1)' class="dealOfDay">Deal of the day</div>`
```methods: { toggleDiv(index) { this.toggle = this.toggle === index ? 0 : index; } }```